# Using recursive and reduce to do the sum of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I wanted to do a recursive function in order to add an array.

Here's the sample array I'm trying to use:
`[[[1, 2, [[3], 4]], 5, []]]`

Since I'm learning, I wanted to try it with reduce... And it's working great, sometimes:

```
const sumItems = function(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return acc + (Array.isArray(x) ? sumItems(x) : x);
  },0);
};
```

The thing is, I would've loved to be able to shorten it... Something like so:

```
const sumItems = function(array) {
  const reducer = (acc, x) => (acc || 0) + (Array.isArray(x) ? sumItems(x) : x);
  return array.reduce(reducer);
};
```

But that's not working at all... I'm not sure why and although I've been playing around with my code, console logging it etc etc etc, the best I can get is an output like this:

`[ [ 1, 2, [ [Array], 4 ] ], 5, [] ]`

Which I find really interesting...

Does someone knows how I could resolve this? Am I doing something wrong that I'm not yet aware of, regarding JavaScript?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Mention the initial value as 0 in your array.reduce() function like return array.reduce(reducer,0); and it will work as your expectations.

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you. I wish I could check both answers to give you credit, they were both quite enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set initial value in reduce method otherwise if the first element is an array then it will fail and returns `NaN` in some iteration and next iteration `acc || 0` will results `0` since `NaN` is falsy value.

```js
var data = [
  [
    [1, 2, [
      [3], 4
    ]], 5, []
  ]
]

const sumItems = function(array) {
  const reducer = (acc, x) => acc + (Array.isArray(x) ? sumItems(x) : x);
  // -now || is not needed --^^^^----- since we'd added initial value so it will be always a number
  // for treating non-digit or non-array value you can replace `x` with `+x || 0` for treating it as `0`
  
  return array.reduce(reducer, 0);
  // ---- initial value-------^^^----
};

console.log(sumItems(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are no longer passing an initial value to `reduce`. Do that instead of trying to `|| 0` the `acc` inside the reducer function.

```
const reducer = (acc, x) => acc + (Array.isArray(x) ? sumItems(x) : x);
const sumItems = array => array.reduce(reducer, 0);
//                                              ^
```

Without an initial value, `reduce` fails on empty arrays.